# Android Device Connectivity in Adobe Flash Pro CS6 Win7 x64

Tags: android, eclipse, flash, air

I'm using a Samsung Galaxy S3 running Android 4.3.  I've installed the latest Samsung Kies as well as the Android SDK.  I'm able to run the Android SDK in Eclipse and properly compile/run/debug applications via Eclipse, but I cannot seem to get it working with Adobe Flash CS6 - it compiles the SWF and hangs on the "Publishing..." progress bar.

AIR 3.2 for Android Settings are correct, and when I compile the SWF to an APK file and then move the file over to the phone via File Manager I am able to install and run applications successfully.  I can't, however, publish directly to the phone or debug on the device over USB.

I've definitely done my research and have been through all the normal stuff like USB debugging and all that.  Everything works great in Eclipse with the Android SDK - just not in Adobe Flash Pro CS6.  I've read in this thread that others simply have not been able to do it either with Samsung devices running Android 4.2.2+  Can anyone shed some definitive light on this issue?

UPDATE: I got it to work!  I had to copy the adb.exe file from the Android SDK to the one being used by Adobe Flash Pro CS6.  I'm working on turning my experience into a blog post with pictures and step-by-step instructions and I will elaborate on every step of the process.  Stay tuned...

Comment: Next time you should read more carefully the SDK upgrade instructions when switching to a higher version SDK.

Comment: @doktorpeace: I have the same problem with Flash CS5.5 and my Samsung Galaxy Note(GT-N7000 running cyanogenmod!) However, your solution didn't seem to work in my case... Can you point to your blog post ? It'd help me tremendously!

Comment: I ended up not making a blog post because a) my case was super simple and b) I found out developing flash for iOS is NOT SUPPORTED in the iTunes store - so it will never be distributed, and for Android it's hit-or-miss with the different OS versions.  I ended up just starting to learn Android development with Java, and I'd really suggest doing the same.  As for your case, I wouldn't have any clue, since I haven't touched Flash in a year.  It could be that Android 4.3+ is not supported in Flash CS5.5.