# Unable to detect android phone via adb

Tags: android, flash, adobe, adb, cyanogenmod

I am using Adobe Flash CS5.5 to develop flash air applications on Android. However, I just can't seem to get my phone visible to Flash.

I have a Samsung Galaxy GT-N7000 (Galaxy Note). I have rooted the phone with cyanogenmod 10.1.3-n7000. I have enabled "usb debugging" in the phone settings. 
I'm running this on Windows 7 Professional 32-bit.

When I connect my phone to the PC, I am able to see it as GT-N7000 under Device Manager -> Portable Devices heading. I am also able to copy files to/from this device without any issues.

The `adb` version installed on my system in the flash installation folder is 1.0.26. When I try to run the flash animation on my phone, it can't seem to detect it. I get the error message 
"Could not find an android device to connect to. Please ensure that you have the phone connected, the correct drivers installed, and the phone has USB device debugging enabled".

I'm at a loss for how to install the usb driver, as mine is a galaxy note, but is using `cyanogenmod`. I couldn't find the `SDK` manager in the flash installation folder, but ran the `SDK` manager from the `android-sdk` folder which I have parallel installed for developing android applications using Android Studio. I installed the Google USB drivers from that location. I'm not sure if this will help Flash detect the phone.

I have also tried using the usb connection mode as MTP, PTP, as well as mass storage. But no difference.

What else could be the issue? Any pointers? Please excuse me if any details are missing. I'll add them as they are pointed out.

**UPDATE**: Found a similar query at [Android Device Connectivity in Adobe Flash Pro CS6 Win7 x64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24480068/android-device-connectivity-in-adobe-flash-pro-cs6-win7-x64).. However, doesn't work for me! :(

Workaround (well, sort of!):I am able to copy the .`apk` file to the phone memory, and then install it. I had to enable "Unknown Sources- Allow installation of apps from unknown sources". **However, I am still not able to publish directly to the phone, nor am I able to debug it from Flash.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it! Since Flash connectivity didn't seem to be working, I thought it better to see if I can at least make Android Studio work with my phone. Tried all the stuff possible, including using the SDK Manager to install the Google USB Driver. Nothing worked.

Since my phone IS a GT-N7000, but with CyanogenMod, I thought that the Samsung USB driver wouldn't work for it.

Finally, after trying a lot with all the other methods, I did the simplest thing possible. Found the Samsung GT-N7000 usb driver (downloaded from the **mirror link** in this XDA forum post http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1755001), installed it, and EVERYTHING started working! Flash, Android Studio, etc!

For those who don't want to download just the drivers, or are hesitant to download from unverified links, you can download and Install **Samsung Kies**, and it'll do the required installation of correct driver!

Duh! Sometimes, the simplest things are the only steps required!

Comment: I'm accepting my own answer, as there were no other replies, and since I did solve my own problem using the steps described.

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: Please see my first answer for a simple way to solve this. If this doesn't work for you, you can try the steps documented here.

I'm posting follow up problems and how I resolved them. Since this *update* was rather long and might not occur for others, I have posted it as a separate answer. It is still pertinent to this question, so I have kept it as an alternate answer.

**

### Moderators: please let me know if there is a more elegant way of doing this, and I will do the needful.

**

**UPDATE:** I had uninstalled Flash for some reason, and re-installed it again after two months or so. However, I found that I was unable to publish to the phone after this. Resolved it finally as below.

Sometimes, even after the device drivers get installed, and show up in device manager as an adb interface, you might not be able to publish to the phone. Ensure that you have enabled "developer options" in the phone, and that "USB debugging" option is enabled. This might solve your problem.

However, in my case, this didn't work. Flash was just stuck at the "Publishing" phase, and didn't proceed to launch my project on the phone.

In such a case, open up a command prompt (in windows) and query the devices using the command "adb devices".

If the device shows up as "offline" status, try connecting the phone to another port. Again, this too didn't work out for me.

Finally, I updated the Platform SDK on my machine using the "SDK Manager". Once updated, I re-ran the command "adb devices" on the command prompt, and voila! The phone is now listed properly without any "offline" status.

Now the problem! The problem is that Flash CS5.5 uses an old version of the Air runtime (which comes with it's own version of adb.exe). In order to update this, I downloaded the latest version of AIR SDK from http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/air-sdk-download.html. However as Flash 5.5 doesn't have a straight-forward way to use the latest version of the SDKthere were some steps that I had to follow to do so. The original document is at http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/enable-the-latest-air-sdk-in-flash-professional-cs55--active-11488, but I am inlining it here based upon my own changes to the steps mentioned in the web page, as well as to ensure that these steps don't become dead links later on.

Step 1: Download the Latest SDK

Download the latest AIR SDK from the following link: http://www.adobe.com/products/air/sdk/
Extract the downloaded file into a separate folder on your desktop

Step 2: Backup Your Current SDK Folder

Go to the Adobe Flash CS5.5 installation folder (
should be "C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Flash CS5.5" on 32 bit Windows, 
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Adobe Flash CS5.5" on 64 bit Windows, and 
"Applications/Adobe Flash CS5.5" on OS X).

Rename the AIR2.6 folder to AIR2.6_OLD.
Create a new folder and name it AIR2.6.

Step 3: Create the New SDK Folder
Copy the contents of the latest AIR SDK folder (that you’ve created on your desktop) to the AIR2.6 folder.
Browse to the AIR2.6/frameworks/libs/air/ folder in the Adobe Flash CS5.5 folder and copy the airglobal.swc file.
Paste the SWC file into Adobe Flash CS5.5/Common/Configuration/ActionScript 3.0/AIR2.6/, overwriting the existing airglobal.swc file.

Step 4: Final Configuration Settings

Go to Adobe Flash CS5.5/Common/Configuration/Players/ and open the following files using a text editor 
(you may need administrative privileges to edit these files in the application folder in Windows):

AdobeAIR2_6.xml
AiriPhone.xml
Android.xml

NOTE: Player element and how to point it to the right version. Go to https://helpx.adobe.com/air/air-releasenotes.html and start counting from 
2.6 version as 11,  to the version updated by you, incrementing every time you see a "user release notes" for each version. For easier reference, 
version 19 should be considered as version 30.

Change the version attribute of the player element from 11 to this calculated version (30 in my case) in each file. 
Don’t forget to save them after you’re done editing.

Restart Flash, and try publishing to the phone. It worked for me! :)